# Scope updated value into a variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, mailgun

I have this:

```
$scope.data = {
    'a' : 0,
    'b' : 0,
    'c' : 0
}
```

... and the values for each with:

```
<input toggle ng-model="data.a" ng-true-value="10" ng-false-value="0" />
```

This is an example of a angularjs v1 ionic quote calculator, each field has a value, and i display the right value with `{{data.a}} {{..}}` and the last field is the sum of all `{{data.a + data.b + data.c ....}}`
I need to pass all the fields real value on a javascript variable in order to send the scope data to email:

```
angular.module('app.mail', []).controller("MailgunController", function($scope, $http) {


    var mailgunUrl = "mydomain.com";
    var mailgunApiKey = window.btoa("api:key-XXXXXXXXXX");
    var recipient = "info@mydomain.com";
    var subject = "Quote";
    var message = "Results: " + $scope.data.a;


    $scope.send = function() {
        $http(
            {
                "method": "POST",
                "url": "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/" + mailgunUrl + "/messages",
                "headers": {

                    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    "Authorization": "Basic " + mailgunApiKey
                },
                data: "from=" + "info@example.com" + "&to=" + recipient + "&subject=" + subject + "&html=" + message 
            }
        ).then(function(success) {
            console.log("SUCCESS " + JSON.stringify(success));
        }, function(error) {
            console.log("ERROR " + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    };
});
```

The problem is that i receive the email with the default value 0:

```
$scope.data.a; // 0
```

How can i get the true scope data value into var message?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you use web api controller on server side when return a result 
pass result to a new{} object. for example:

```
           [HttpPost]
            public HttpResponseMessage Insert(LookupViewModel model)
            {
                try
                {
                    EducationLookup result = AutoMapperGenericsHelper<LookupViewModel, EducationLookup>.ConvertToDBEntity(model);
                    this.Uow.EducationLookups.Add(result);
                    Uow.Commit(User.Id);
                   //Look here
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new{Result= result});
                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
                {
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, CustomExceptionHandler.HandleDbEntityValidationException(e));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.HResult.HandleCustomeErrorMessage(ex.Message));
                }

            }
```

Get json format on success function on client side.

Comment: Thank you but i think it will not work, i m using ionic creator, on the page i have 20 fields, like toggle, range, select, each one has a value declared with directives like ng-false-value and ng-true-value. The ng-models are saved into scope.data, with 0 value, cause on the app i have an output on each field that updates automatically on user interaction like: Domain: 0 €, if the user activates the domain toggle it shows 15 €, if i set default value as null or false it will bind null € or false €.

Comment: In order to send the data without using the phone email aplication, i added the mailgun api, it works but the value recived is 0.

Comment: i m an angularjs and javascript newbie, i don t know how to bind on a variable.

Comment: Binding variables methods on angularjs:

Comment: One way binding(read only): you can used ng-bind or {{}}
Two way binding(read/write): you can used ng-model

Answer (score 0):

```
 $scope.send = function() {
        $http(
            {
                "method": "POST",
                "url": "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/" + mailgunUrl + "/messages",
                "headers": {

                    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    "Authorization": "Basic " + mailgunApiKey
                },
                data: "from=" + "info@example.com" + "&to=" + recipient + "&subject=" + subject + "&html=" + message 
            }
        ).then(function(respose) {
            //Get server response in block! 
            $scope.data=respose;
            console.log("Send e-mail was successful");
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
```